# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento-1.7, database

It appears to have this error message on every product page. Any idea about why this happened and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This means sql query is not working. Check your /var/report or /var/log folder to check what's going on. Add more detail so we can answer your question.

Comment: You might want a developer to look at this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have custom code going on which is trying to join something to your product model. However, the join is being done on an incorrect field - product_id does not exist, it should be entity_id instead.

Disable the custom modules one by one until you can identify which is causing the problem then you can consult them for further help, or provide more information about what your doing to help identify the problem.